# Return the count of every first row/observation in a Multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, multi-index

I have a multi-index dataframe:

```
                  pid  time
 id_main  id_sub 
   
 id_1   sub_id1  pid1   t1
        sub_id3  pid2   t2
        sub_id9  pid3   t3
           .       .    .
           .       .    .
 id_2   sub_id2  pid_1  t1
        sub_id3  pid_1  t2
          .        .     .
          .        .     .
```

**Context**: Every `id_main` is a users individual session id and the `pid` is a string containing the "path" where a user traveled (once we sort by time of course)

> df = df.set_index(['main_id','sub_id'])` 
> df = df.sort_values('time')

**Goal**: I want to find the count for every FIRST pid for everything session. So I want to essentially have a series that has the `pid` as the index (so I can merge it elsewhere) and a single column with the number of times each `pid` occurred first for every session `(id_1, id_2, ... , id_n)`. Then a little bit more complicated but I am looking to create another dataframe that has the number of occurrences for each page according to session id (`id_main`) and then a second index containing all the `pids` and their relative count. So basically, I need the first occurrence for every session, and for each of those first `pids` I'm hoping to have a count of all their respective next steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the rows with first page per session:

```
>>> df.groupby('id_main')['time'].idxmin()
id_main
id1    (id1, sub0)
id2    (id2, sub7)
id3    (id3, sub5)
Name: time, dtype: object
```

So the number each first page happens:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby('id_main')['time'].idxmin(), 'pid'].value_counts()
pid8     1
pid13    1
pid1     1
Name: pid, dtype: int64
```

Of course in this example I only have 3 users each starting at a different page.

Then you want the number of occurrences for each page per session (to which you can potentially add a `.unstack('pid')`):

```
>>> df.groupby('id_main')['pid'].value_counts()
id_main  pid  
id1      pid14    1
         pid5     1
         pid8     1
id2      pid13    1
         pid15    1
         pid5     1
id3      pid1     1
         pid10    1
         pid11    1
         pid14    1
         pid15    1
         pid7     1
Name: pid, dtype: int64
```

If you want to know page transitions, i.e. from which page to the next, you can do as follows:

```
>>> df.sort_values('time').groupby('id_main')['pid'].shift().to_frame('from_pid').join(df.sort_values('time')['pid'].rename('to_pid'))
               from_pid to_pid
id_main id_sub                
id3     sub5        NaN   pid1
        sub1       pid1  pid14
id2     sub7        NaN  pid13
id1     sub0        NaN   pid8
        sub8       pid8   pid5
id3     sub0      pid14   pid7
id1     sub4       pid5  pid14
id3     sub4       pid7  pid11
id2     sub2      pid13   pid5
id3     sub8      pid11  pid15
        sub3      pid15  pid10
id2     sub3       pid5  pid15
```

This could be useful for a model to know from which page to which it’s going, maybe a simple markov chain is a good start.

Comment: Much appreciated..I will review your solution over the weekend and I will respond with any questions and/or approve your answer :)